# Techniques that use the addition of noise to training data

Tags: cross-validation, overfitting

I was curious if there is a class of techniques that uses addition of noise to training data to help prevent overfitting of data.

Any references would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you want, but [this paper:  Bootstrapping with Noise: An Effective Regularization Technique](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=90C06480E22D8E85A911295D1B717228?doi=10.1.1.7.1266&rep=rep1&type=pdf) describes adding noise to training examples as an effective regularisation technique.